# Cascade of Objective c syntax errors when including c++ library in an objective c++ file

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, objective-c++

This is my first post so please excuse me if I fail to follow any posting conventions.
I have been working on an app using a "Cocoa/Objective C" front end in xcode 4.6.2 on OSX 10.7.5, and accessing c++ libraries via Objective c++ adaptor classes.
Its been a steep learning curve, but things have been going well. I have now hit a stumbling block that I hope someone on here knows how to fix.

I recently included a new library in my c++ backend, which works perfectly in my 'C++ only' backend experimentation xcode project. But when I try to compile my `ObjC/Objc++/C++` version, I get cascading syntax errors in the Objective C++ file, approximately like this:

```
In Objc++.mm:
#include "objCclass.h"    //no problem here
#include "CppBackend.h"   //c++ libs included by this file cause the following errors:

@interface objCclass ()   //!unexpected '@' in program
-(id)classmethods      //(class extension to allow access to c++ backend)
@end                  //!end must appear in an objective c context

//etc,etc....
@synthesize x,y,z;   //!Missing context for property implementation declaration
//errors on most lines that work fine when CppBackend.h is not included
```

Other So posts on similar subjects suggest inane syntax errors causing this problem often, but I'm think this is not the case here. My Cocoa front end works without the backend include, and the backend works perfectly by itself in a c++ only project.

I'd be very greatly for any help. Much appreciation for all the help from people on here for this and other issues.

Marc

**UPDATE** - I have found that if I comment out the class extensions (and remove any subsequence dependency issues) - it works! Is it possible that there is a problem in the ObjC++ compiler that it doesnt like seeing class extensions?

Comment: Try writing a file that contains `#include "CppBackend.h"` and nothing else, then see if it compiles as both C++ and Objective-C++.

Comment: You made sure the file type is set to Objective C++ right? http://i.stack.imgur.com/ogeaF.png for Xcode 4.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Dietrich - I made a new, empty Cocoa app, changed to AppDelegate.mm, included the backend.h, and it does seem to compile, which is really good news, and I guess means that the problem is a something in my project rather than an inherent issue library incompatibility. I am very glad to have found this out. Not sure what to do next though.....

Comment: Nighthawk - yeah its set to Objective c++ and called .mm :)

Comment: Your include file does not end cleanly.  There is a dangling statement of some sort at the end.

Comment: But how come the backend works fine in a c++ only environment. Wouldnt a dangling statement like that make it fail there also?

Comment: Dietrich - I have managed to compile and run a Command Line App renamed to main.mm and including the backend, and also a Cocoa App, renamed to .mm and including the backend. All good. How do I troubleshoot this? Im normally quite methodical, but this feels like a brick wall.

Comment: What happens if you don't include "objCClass.h"?

Comment: @user1118321 - hard to say - the class is needed many times in the file, so I cant just comment it out and try to run..... Commenting it out leads to the same result... compiler doesnt get as far as noticing the absence of objCClass definition, just flags the aforementioned cascade of syntax errors..

Comment: CppBackend.h includes a file "CppLibrary.h". When I comment out CppLibrary inside CppBackend.h, the Cocoa front end runs fine. How nested can this problem be?????

Comment: I've seen this sort of problem many times.  Often it's a missing `}` or `;` near the end of the include.  Can be confounded by #if statements that give you different flow depending.  Can be confounded if the error is inside an include inside an include inside an include.  Some things will compile right, others won't.  Can even cause a "silent" problem where later statements are "swallowed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue.

The c++ library I was trying to include declared a typedef "interface", which I assume was really upsetting the "@interface" of objective c. I renamed the typedef and all subsequent uses to '_interface', and now it all works!!!

Many thanks to all who offered help on this. I had a intuitive feeling that it wasnt a syntax error, and was some sort of clash between the two libraries.

:):):):):):):):):)

Answer (score 1):

To fight against preprocessor errors you need to see its actual output.

In Xcode, select offending source file, click 'Related files' button on the top left corner of source pane, then click 'Preprocess'.

[image: Preprocess menu command]

Comment: thanks for that. Do you have an tips for how to diagnose this preprocessor output?

Comment: @MarcSpecter Preprocessing makes single output file with all the header files included. You could look for the offending line in it (by searching for keywords shown in the error messages). Or, save it as another .mm file and compile, to see where from the typo errors start (if it is really a typo problem).

Comment: thanks. I will keep looking. I really do think that this isnt a typo problem. Happy to be wrong though :)

Comment: compiling the preprocessed output gives many typedef redefinition errors